# Interop.word addpicture method not displaying image

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, office-interop

I'm attempting to generate a word document in VB.Net with a logo in the top left, and the addpicture method I'm using is running successfully (not generating errors), but no image is being displayed in my word document.

The image is in my img folder sitting in the same directory as the page file.

My code is as follows:

```
para.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(Server.MapPath("img/logo.png"))
para.Range.Text = "Quad Chart"
para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
```

If needed I can insert the complete code, but as I said, not errors are being generated, the word document is successfully generated but without the image.

Ideas? Other ways I should be trying to add the image?

Comment: I tried that and while neither way generates an error, it doesn't display the image either.

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: What would you suggest instead?

Comment: Anything that works would be better than something that doesn't work.